# Shouldn't 1 mole of any ideal gas at open space occupy more than 22.4 L volume at S.T.P. due to diffusion?

Tags: gas-laws

So if diffusion occurs,1 mole of any ideal gas should occupy a much greater volume in open space at STP.

Comment: Well, we are assuming we are putting the gas in a container (with variable volume). Otherwise it's meaningless to talk about the volume of a gas, right?

Comment: Standard pressure was redefined in 1982. Now the IUPAC definition of STP is such that a mole of gas has a volume of 22.7 liters at STP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure

Answer (score 5):

Here is the calculation for the volume occupied by one mole ($n$) of an ideal gas at STP (temperature $T = 273.15\ \mathrm K$, pressure $P = 1\ \mathrm{bar}$):

gas constant: $R = 0.08314\ \mathrm{L\ bar\ mol^{-1}\ K^{-1}}$
ideal gas law: $PV = nRT$

$$\begin{align}
V &= \frac{nRT}{P}\\[6pt]  
&= \mathrm{\frac{1\ mol\ \times\ 0.08314\ L\ bar\ mol^{-1}\ K^{-1} \times\ 273.15\ K}{1\ bar}}\\[6pt] 
&= 22.71\ \mathrm L
\end{align}$$

Another way of looking at this of course is that any 22.71 liter chunk of particulate-free air, of arbitrary shape, will contain about 1 mole of air. Molecules of the different gases composing the air will diffuse in to and out of this region, but it will always contain about 1 mol of air at STP.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal gas equation defines the relationship between temperature, pressure, volume and quantity. The situation it models is how some of those variables change when others are altered.

For a fixed quantity (1 mole) of gas at STP all the variables are fixed except volume. But the situation you describe does not have a fixed volume.

What you should imagine doing with the equation is this. Put 1 mole of gas into a vessel where you can measure the pressure and volume while keeping the temperature constant. The equation describes how the pressure and volume will vary as you change one or the other *within the vessel*. When the pressure is 1atm, the volume will be 22.7 litres. If you now open the vessel, you no longer have a fixed *volume* and the equation is irrelevant. The gas will diffuse into the room and eventually will have mixed with the atmosphere.

You could still use the equation to measure the density of the atmosphere. The atmosphere has a fixed pressure and, assuming the mix of gases behaves in an ideal way (a good approximation) you can tell that the number of moles of gas in a given volume should conform to the ideal gas equation (i.e. 22.7L at STP). If you know the mix of compounds making up the atmosphere the mass will be the weighted average of the molar masses of the constituents.

Answer (score 1):

If diffusion occurs, either the pressure or temperature (or both) of the system is affected such that the system is not at STP.
Simply rearrange $PV = n\mathrm RT$ into $V = n\mathrm R \times \frac TP$.

Assuming constant moles $n$, the pressure or temperature must change.